# How to add a property on a type which is an array of objects?

Tags: typescript

I have the following type:

```
type MyType = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}[];
```

How do I add a new property to this object?

E.g: add `{ fooBar: string }` to `MyType` so the result is:

```
type MyType = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  fooBar: string;
}[];
```

The best that I could do is this. It works, but it is quite cumbersome and I guess that something more elegant could be used

```
type Solution = Array<
  MyType extends Array<infer Item> ? Item & { fooBar: string } : never
>;
```

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by getting the inner array item type by indexing the array type with `number`.  After that, create an intersection with the new things you would like to be on the array item type.  Finally, just create a new array type with that newly created item type:

```
type MyType = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}[];

type MyBetterType = (MyType[number] & { fooBar: string; })[];
// ^? ({ foo: string; bar: string; } & { fooBar: string; })[]
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKUBmA9gQFxQDOwATgJYB2A5gNza4BGAhpaRTQ81gF8A2gF1+2UJFggAQhGDAIlRFNQAKOCohDaAVwC2rJSKgAydPiIzO3KnSZQBASlH8A9G9xQAegH4gA)

Comment: Wow, I was ridiculously complicating things =D Thank you for the class =)

Comment: Could I ask you another question in addition? Let's say that we had a type like this:

```type Example = {

props: {

foo: string
}[]

}```. How to do the same above, but altering a subtype of a type in this case, adding
 ```
{bar: string}
``` to the object type declared in ```props```?

Comment: @Alioshr https://tsplay.dev/WG5K9N but I advise you always ask questions in questions and only put comments in comments